# The Gambler's Ruin without using random walks

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is more of a doubt. I understand that this problem can be described with Markov chains and the recursion solved without much trouble. However I've seen that some people casually say that

$$
P(M_i)=P(M_i|W)P(W)+P(M_i|¬W)P(¬W)
$$

where $M_i$ is the event with $i$ cents, $W$ is the event of winning; they state that by The Law of Total Probability, the above equation holds. However, I can't get around the use of "plain" total probability here, because the $W$ implies some kind of change. You may argue that it applies when thinking of it as a weighted state-change, but just total probability over $P(M_i)$? I think I am missing something here if we *don't* see it as a weighted change of states.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure I see the question.  You needn't think of this as state transitions if you don't want to.  $P(M_i)$ is a statement about paths and $W$ is just an attribute of the path; specifically it is the attribute that the first step on the path is a Win.  Viewed this way, the formula is exactly set up for the Law of Total Probability.  Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @lulu this may be answering it. I think that the nature of the problem is of random walks and states, but at least today a professor didn't mention it in terms of states rather than just conditioning $M_i$ itself.

Comment: Personally, I frequently find states a useful alternative to enumerations, especially when the possible paths loop back through the same state a lot.  Take the problem of two people tossing a coin until HH is realized.  Theoretically you can have arbitrarily long paths, but really it's either decided quickly or you return to a state you've been to before.  Makes for a simple recursion.

Comment: @lulu I like states too. Once we've found the recursive relation, how would you interpret it? As in being presented with the formula and just asked to explain intuitively why it works.